# What different topological properties do spaces of different separation axioms have?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, axioms, separation-axioms

What different topological properties do  spaces of different separation axioms have?

I am looking for somehow "categorizing" topological (and non-topological) properties of spaces according to their separation axioms. (e.g. how functions behave, what properties may coincide...)

I have never seen any complex view on this topic.

What I have in mind is something like Venn diagrams from the most general separation axiom to the most "strict" ... And for each $T_i$ the properties that hold for spaces satisfying that axiom.

For example, for Tychonoff spaces, one of the properties would be that they admit Hausdorff compactifications etc.

Could you recommend any resource where to find such view? Or can you think of any properties specific for the individual separation axioms?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: There is a lesser-known space, an Uryssohn space, which should be  called a $T_{2\frac 1 2}$ space (although it isn't). In an Uryssohn space, any 2 distinct points have nbhds whose closures are disjoint.  And there is the $T_{\frac 1 2}$ space, in which every 1-member subset is open or closed (or both).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One book that may be of interest is [Counterexamples in topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology). It gives a long lists of topological spaces with their properties. This would provide you with lots of counterexamples to theorems when the separation axiom required is relaxed a bit (as in "[Theorems] holds for $T_2$ spaces but [Space] gives a $T_1$ counterexample")

Comment: Thank you, I have actually searched something in this book few times! This is the type of an answer I hoped for

Comment: +1. I would recommend a good text on general topology, e.g. Introduction To Topology And Modern Analysis by Simmons, or General Topology by Engelking.